# want the max and used from string

Tags: powershell

```
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/24036900/175063

$user = "uuuu"
$pwd = "pppp"
$source = "http://1.1.1.1/manager/jmxproxy?get=java.lang:type=Memory&att=HeapMemoryUsage"
$destination = "D:\Work\ps\test.xml"
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$p = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy 'http://proxy:8080'
$p.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$wc.proxy = $p
$credCache = New-Object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pwd)
$credCache.Add($source, "Basic", $creds)
$wc.Credentials = $credCache
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $destination)

# max=1445462016, used=898674904
# free

foreach ($thing in Get-Content $destination) {
    $max = $thing.split("max=")
    $used = $thing.split("used=")

    Write-Host $max
    Write-Host $used
}

#$free = $max - $used
#Write-Host $free
```

The string the file that is downloaded is a one-liner:

```
OK - Attribute get 'java.lang:type=Memory' - HeapMemoryUsage= javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=java.lang.management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)))),contents={committed=1444478976, init=1494220800, max=1445462016, used=868228272})
```

And all I really want from it is:

```
max=1445462016
used=868228272
```

to be:

```
1445462016-868228272=577233744
```

Answer (score 2):

I would extract the values from the `contents={...}` portion of the string with a regular expression, replace the commas with newlines and convert the result to a hashtable. Then you just need to cast the values to integers for the calculation.

```
Get-Content $destination | Where-Object {
  $_ -match ',contents=\{(.+?)\}'
} | ForEach-Object {
  $values = $matches[1] -replace ', ', "`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData

  $free = [int]$values['max'] - [int]$values['used']

  'Max:  {0}' -f $values['max']
  'Used: {0}' -f $values['used']
  'Free: {0}' -f $free
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I interpreted this correctly, do you want to display this in the console or store it in a variable, I'm assuming console here:

```
write-host "$max-$used="($max-$used)
```

Comment: My issue is that is am not able to parse or get max or used values..  I know how to do the math part..

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my own solution...  I know it may not be the best way, but seems to work..

```
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/24036900/175063

$user="uuuu"
$pwd="pppp"
$source="http://1.1.1.1/manager/jmxproxy?get=java.lang:type=Memory&att=HeapMemoryUsage"
$destination="D:\Work\ps\test.xml"
$wc=new-object System.Net.WebClient
$p = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy 'http://proxy:8080'
$p.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$wc.proxy=$p
$credCache=new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds=new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pwd)
$credCache.Add($source, "Basic", $creds)
$wc.Credentials=$credCache
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $destination)

# max=1445462016, used=898674904
# free

foreach ($thing in Get-Content $destination) {
    # , max=1445462016, used=696318832})
    # $a = $a.substring(2,3)
    # MID: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176901.aspx
    # LEN: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176895.aspx
    # Instr: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176876.aspx
    $len = $thing.length
    $maxst = $thing.indexof("max=")
    $usedst = $thing.indexof("used=")

    $max=$thing.substring($maxst+4,$len-$usedst-6)
    $used=$thing.substring($usedst+5,$len-$usedst-7)
    $free=$max-$used

    # , max=1445462016, used=696318832})

    write-host $len
    write-host $maxst
    write-host $usedst
    write-host $max
    write-host $used
    write-host $free
}
```